# Socket Exception : Connection Reset

Tags: java, sockets

```
    Socket Soc=new Socket("whois.internic.net",43);//Creating a Socket.
    InputStream In=Soc.getInputStream();  //Getting Input Stream
    OutputStream Out=Soc.getOutputStream(); //Getting Output Stream
    String Str="MHProfessional.com";
    Out.write(Str.getBytes());
    int c;
    while((c=In.read())!= -1) { //this is line 11!..Commenting it out works fine.
        System.out.print((char)c);
    }
    Soc.close();
```

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJdbx.png)

How do i Solve it. It gives same error on eclipse and on jdk..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `WHOIS`request is terminated by `\r\n`. Your request isn't legal, so the peer is closing the connection, or perhaps even resetting it. Or perhaps that server just won't service your client.

Comment: then how do i fix it.

Comment: Err, terminate your request with `\r\n`?

Comment: i need you to enlighten me on that \r\n where do i put it

Comment: Err, at the end of the request? Surely you understand what 'terminate' means?